# � appearing when loading text file with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I´m loading a text file called descripcion.txt and displaying it in my div called #descripcionContenedor, but when it gets displayed in the browser aparently UTF-8 is not working because im getting "�" instead of "¿".
Here is my code:

## jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#description").ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "textFiles/descripcion.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "charset=utf-8",
        success : function (data) {
            $("#description").html(data);
        }
    });
 });
});
```

## TXT file:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"    />
<h2 style="margin-bottom: 0;">¿Que es esta pagina web?</h2></br>
```

## PHP file:

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
          <div id="descripcionContenedor">
                <p id="description"></p>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saving your text file (with Windows Notepad), make sure the encoding is set properly.

> [image]

You could also simply replace all your question marks with `&iquest;` the html entity. That way, encoding won't matter (when you involve databases it's much easier too).